# Products don't show in catalog -> product management

Tags: magento

After importing products, they don't show up in catalog. Neither in `admin->catalog->product mangement`, but they **do** show in `catalog->categories management` as products of the category.

I've rebuilt indexes and re-created caches... Any idea of what might have gone wrong?

Magento version 1.6.1

Comment: Couple of questions: How are you importing the products? Have you refreshed your cache and indexes?

Comment: Show the import code so we may help. If they are showing up in the category tree but ot in your product management, this would indicate you are missing a necessary field on your import.

Comment: Thanks all for your insterest, after retrying the import, now it works.

Comment: Thanks all for your insterest, after retrying the import, now it works. Don't know exactly where the problem was, might be it had something to do qith the language, the shop is in spanish and Field like "status" or "visibility" behabe in diferent ways if the import is done using the magentos administration or if it is done programatically from php. In the first case those fields' values must be in spanish ("Habilitado","Deshabilitado" or "Catálogo, Búsqueda")  but if the import is done from command line using php script they must be in english "Enabled","Disabled" or "Catalog,Seacrh"

Answer (score 0):

How about product status? "Enabled" or "Disabled"! Did you check?

Comment: In the end this had something to do with the problem, the values for the status depend on the language of the shop.

Comment: This is obviously not the answer to products not appearig in catalog management. people should not accept answers that did not help them, as it will confuse future readers.